# Streamlit: NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Tags: python, null, nameerror, streamlit

I am new to streamlit and have finished my script for a predictor regression, using the California house price dataset. However, when I try to run the .py file I encounter the following error:

```
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

Traceback:

```
File "c:\users\cupac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 354, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)

File "C:\Users\cupac\desktop\untitled.py", line 188, in <module>
    "execution_count": null,
```

Comment: ``null`` is a JSON keyword; Python's equivalent is ``None``. Are you trying to "load" JSON, or did you erroneously write JSON instead of Python?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error. If you open your filename.py file, you will be seeing a JSON content of the code. This is primarily because you might have saved the file as .py directly from the Jupyter notebook. You can clear all the contents and try the following code

```
import streamlit as st

st.write('Hello world')
```

which will open your contents in a new browser.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about Streamlit, but I know that there is `None` instead of `null` in Python. You can try to define `null = None` in your script `C:\Users\cupac\desktop\untitled.py` at the top - it might work!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).